# How can I get inline and online help within Android Studio's editor?

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio. Is there any way to get the same full help experience as Visual Studio provides (ie. inline help and F1 for browser online help) but within Android Studio?

Comment: Please don't editorialize. Your personal bias in favour of one tool over another is entirely irrelevant to your question. Focus on what you _actually_ want to know. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question (as of Android Studio 3.0.1) ...

**For Inline / Context Help via mouse hovering:**

*File > Settings > Editor > General > [Check On] Show Quick Documentation On Mouse Move*

**For Online Documentation Help when pressing the F1 key:**

*File > Settings > Keymap > Main Menu > View > Tools Windows > External Documentation* [Dclick and "Add Keyboard Shortcut" > Hit the F1 key]

For the Online Documentation approach you will have to override the Other > Context Help key since it uses F1 already (quite useless since all it does is go to IntelliJ).

For the record F1 / Shift+F1 online documentation isnt exhaustive.  It seems Google maps some words to the appropriate documentation and others they do not leaving you wondering why F1 isnt shelling out to the browser for several commands.